# Discrete subset of a separable and normal space is countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be separable and normal. Suppose $A\subset X$ is discrete in the relative topology. I'd like to show that $A$ is countable. By separability, it suffices to exhibit a mutually disjoint collection of non-empty open sets indexed by $A$.

The fact that $A$ is discrete means that, for each $a\in A$, there exists an open set $U_a\subset X$ such that $U_a\cap A=\{a\}$. The problem is that the $U_a$ need not be pairwise disjoint.

We know that $a\not\in U_a^c$, which is closed, so by Urysohn's lemma we can choose $f_a\in C(X,[0,1])$ such that $f_a(a)=1$ and $f_a(U_a^c)=\{0\}$. My idea was to use these $f_a$ to somehow shrink the sets $U_a$ and obtain a collection that is pairwise disjoint, but I wasn't able to come up with something that works. Any hints?

Comment: I would try to find a counterexample by playing around with the double arrow ($[0,1]\times\{0,1\}$ with the topology induced by the lexicographic order)... I'm not sure if this is true without the hypothesis of $A$ being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X=[0,1]^\mathbb{R}$ in the product topology, then $X$ is compact Hausdorff (so normal) and separable (Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem) while $C = \{f \in X: \exists p \in \mathbb{R}: (f(p) = 1 \land \forall x \neq p: f(x) = 0) \}$ is discrete in the subspace topology and of uncountable size $\mathfrak{c}$. So you'd have to at least assume that your discrete subspace $C$ is closed as well.

Assuming $C$ is closed, the standard Urysohn function argument from Jones' lemma immediately implies that $2^{|C|} \le 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$. That last fact does *not* necessarily imply that $C$ is at most countable: there are models of ZFC where $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0}$, e.g. and under MA there are spaces $X$ that are normal and separable and have a closed discrete subspace of size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is $X$ separable? Wouldn't this contradict that $\{\{d\}:d\in D\}$ is an uncountable family of mutually disjoint non-empty open sets? What am I missing? Also, I had wondered what happened is $C$ also happened to be closed, so thank you for the additional comments!

Comment: @Reveillark sorry, the original example was too naive and non-separable. The updated large product example is OK.

Comment: Great, thanks you very much!